# How to attach string value to image picker intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my android app, I attach a string value to my image picker event. I then want to get it back, but it keeps getting a null value.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Intent image_chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_picture));
        image_chooser.putExtra("type", "6"); 
        startActivityForResult(image_chooser, SELECT_PICTURE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String type = data.getExtras().getString("type");  // -- > null
        if (type.equals("5")) {
            Bitmap bitmap = MyImage.GetBitmapFromPath(this, data.getData(), 240, 180);
            new Async_up_image(bitmap, NavigationScreen.CategoryWhosOptionsClicked);
        } else {
            analyze(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you need to send type to image picker ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Intent image_chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_picture));
map.put(SELECT_PICTURE,"6");
startActivityForResult(image_chooser, SELECT_PICTURE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode==SELECT_PICTURE) {
           String type = map.get(requestCode);
           if (type.equals("5")) {
               Bitmap bitmap = MyImage.GetBitmapFromPath(this, data.getData(), 240, 180);
               new Async_up_image(bitmap, NavigationScreen.CategoryWhosOptionsClicked);
           } else {
               analyze(data);
           }
         }
    }
}
```